# Dojo accessing js object outside js file

Tags: javascript, scope, dojo, dgrid

I have a **Dojo** application with a **Dgrid**. I would like to push the **javascript** that holds the **dgrid** data to the server. I am having problems accessing the **javascript** object outside of the **javascript** file.

The application form uses a **dojo wizard** therefore when the user clicks next on the **wizard** to move to another page i would like to submit the data (**javascript** object) from the current page to the server for validation and processing.

The issue i am facing is with the **javascript** object's scope. I moved the **javascript** object (*studentData*) into a global scope however the problem persists. Under is some code from the js file and my form wizard:

**Javascript function that creates dgrid**

```
//imports Dojo items
require([ "dojo/parser", "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/store/Memory",

], function(parser, declare, Memory, OnDemandGrid, ColumnSet, Selection,
        selector, Keyboard, DijitRegistry, editor, ColumnHider, ready, Dialog,
        on, registry, Observable, lang) {

    var studentData = [ {
        id : "1",
        age : "33",
        idtype : "1",
        first_name : "Edward",
        surname : "Davis"
    }, {
        id : "2",
        age : "41",
        idtype : "2",
        first_name : "Lewis",
        surname : "Holl"
    }, {
        id : "3",
        age : "59",
        idtype : "3",
        first_name : "Fred",
        surname : "James"
    } ];

    dojo.ready(function() {
        // Code
        function byId(Id) {

            return document.getElementById(Id);
        }

    });

    var aliasStore = new dojo.store.Observable(new Memory({
        data : aliasData,
        idProperty : "id"
    }));
    var CustomStudentGrid = declare([ OnDemandGrid, selector, Selection,
            Keyboard, editor, DijitRegistry, ColumnHider ]);
    var studentGrid = new CustomStudentGrid({
        store : studentData,
        columns : {
            id : {
                label : "Id",
                field : "id",
                hidden : true
            },

            idtype : {
                label : "Id Code",
                field : "idtype",
                hidden : true
            },

            chkBox : selector({}),

            first_name : {
                label : "First Names",
                field : "first_name"
            },
            surname : {
                label : "Surname",
                field : "surname"
            }

        },
        selectionMode : "none",
        loadingMessage : "Loading data...",
        noDataMessage : "No results found....",
        allowSelectAll : true
    }, "studentGrid");

    aliasNameGrid.on('dgrid-select', function(event) {

        for ( var i in selectedRows) {

            event.rows[i].element.className = "deleteRow";

        }

    });

    aliasNameGrid.on('dgrid-deselect', function(event) {

        for ( var i in deSelectedRows) {
            // alert('Deselected Rows are ' + i);
            event.rows[i].element.classList.remove('deleteRow');

        }
    });

    studentGrid.refresh();

});
```

**Wizard Form**

**When the user clicks on the next button 'passFunction' calls 'Send Form' function**

How can i access the **studentData** in the **SendForm** function or in any other **javascript** file. **studentData** will be manipulated by the user on the **grid**

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function SendForm(dojo) {

        console.log('Entered...');
        console.log(studentData.id[0]);
        };
</script>

<title>Student</title>
</head>
<body class="claro">

<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="student_form" name="student_form">

<div dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" id="StudentWizPane" passFunction="SendForm">
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.TableContainer"
                data-dojo-props="cols:1,customClass:'employee_labels', labelWidth:180"
                id="StudentContainer">

            <div id= "studentGrid"></div>

</div>  

<!-- Other pages -->
```

**Firebug Error**

Under the Script tab i am seeing:

```
Object { error="Mozilla error: invalid scope variables"}
```

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle with demo?

Comment: it would be abit difficult to provide a fiddle since dgrid is a stand alone plugin and it isn't hosted like dojo

Answer (score 0):

If you really want `studentData` to be global, just remove `var` keyword. However, I assume you would like to actually get edited data from grid, in that case I would do something like:

```
diji.byId("studentGrid").store.query({})...
```

Comment: All the edited data is pushed back to studentData so I was looking at sending that object to the server. I am still unclear about your recommendation. Even if I remove the var keyword the object is inaccessible.